# Test for NoMethodError: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, undefined

I have multiple devices and when going into each device separate the information gets pulled.
However, occasionally a device does not hold to standards and will not return the information I'm looking for and get an error message:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the line that causes the issue:

```
<%= @device['summary.usrate']['_value'] %>
```

How can this be tested as to print 'blank' if the error occurs and the variable if available?

```
<%= if @device['summary.usrate']['_value'] != nil print this_variable %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs because @device['summary.usrate'] is nil. Try this: <%= @device['summary.usrate']['key'] if @device['summary.usrate'] %>

Answer (score 0):

That seems to work for me.
I have also tried the following which I tested and it works:

```
<% if defined?(@device['summary.dsrate']['_value']) %>
   <%= @device['summary.dsrate']['_value'] %>
<% end %>
```